# how to find the coordinates of a triangle for the roof?

Tags: geometry, libgosu

I want to put that blue triangle that is in the picture on my red house. i keep putting random number but i can not get it right. the problem is in the Gosu.draw_triangle section. people said this website will help https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/master/Gosu.draw_triangle but i didn't get anything good out of it.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJjfH.png)

```
def initialize 
 def initialize
    super(800, 600, false)
  end

  def draw
    Gosu.draw_rect(310, 300, 200, 150, Gosu::Color::RED, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
    Gosu.draw_rect(385, 380, 50, 70, Gosu::Color::BLUE, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
    Gosu.draw_rect(460, 335, 35, 35, Gosu::Color::BLUE, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
    Gosu.draw_rect(0, 450, 1000, 400, Gosu::Color::GREEN, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
    Gosu.draw_rect(200, 100, 100, 45, Gosu::Color::WHITE, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
    Gosu.draw_rect(100 , 350, 45, 120, 0xff_AC5B13 , ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
    Gosu.draw_triangle(20, 30, Gosu::Color::BLUE, 440, 230,  Gosu::Color::BLUE, 50, 345,  Gosu::Color::BLUE, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry, not programming.

Comment: The code you posted isn't even syntactically valid Ruby code. Also, the nested method definition is extremely confusing.

Comment: i did put geometry in the tag @JörgWMittag. and it is programming

Comment: To place blue triangle on house top, you need at least make Y-coordinates the same as rectangle top for two vertices of triangle

Comment: @jack OK, so I made answer based on that comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place blue triangle on house top, you need to make Y-coordinates the same as rectangle top for two vertices of triangle.

Needed rectangle vertices : `ToplLeft, TopRight`

Triangle vertices:

```
X1 = ToplLeft.X - OverhangSize
Y1 = ToplLeft.Y
X2 = ToplRight.X + OverhangSize
Y2 = ToplLeft.Y
X3 = (ToplLeft.X + ToplRight.X) / 2    //average vor symmetric roof
Y3 = ToplLeft.Y - RoofHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Juts change the number to this. X1 = 405 y1 = 204 x2 = 290 y2 =300 x3 = 530 y3 = 300  [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5tO9.png)

Gosu.draw_triangle(405, 204, Gosu::Color::BLUE, 290, 300,  Gosu::Color::BLUE, 530, 300,  Gosu::Color::BLUE, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)